# Fire a server side method on aspx page immediately after an interrupt

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

Imagine that I have an aspx page that is home page of my site and users spend their times at it. Now I need after occurring an occurrence, this page become update. For example if a new user joined to website all users see it on their home page.
I use a ajax timer for solving my problem and one method is called every one second and if my site has been changed, I can show it to users. But this is no good solution. Please tell me how I can fire a method immediately after an interrupt like above example.
(I think yahoo mail use this way too when we get some new emails)
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

you can make the current thread 'sleep' entil new changes comes up. Each web request correspont to a thread. and you need to use a global collection to keep track of all currenlt sleeping thread.

```
var lastMsgTime=Global.NewMsgTime;  
while(true){     
     Thread.Sleep(300);  
     if(!Response.IsClientConnected||RequeGlobal.NewMsgTime!=lastMsgTime){
          lastMsgTime!=Global.NewMsgTime;
          break;  
     }  
}
```

you'll still be using ajax on client side.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I call my method and change home page?<br/> For example fill a list box on the home page.

Comment: if you're using ASP.NET controls. Reloading the page from client side may be the most simple solution (location.reload();). Otherwise you can consider manipulating DOM using JavaScript and JSON-formatted data if you want better user-expierence.

Comment: ie. once Global.NewMsgTime changed, reload all the client pages.

Comment: Could you give me a sample code please?
I don't want to reload my page (I want to reload a part of my page using ajax or open a new page or something else )